# How to check the subscription status before showing the first view in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, in-app-purchase, subscription, auto-renewable

I implemented subscription (Auto renewal purchase) in Swift. I want to show a button in the first View if user already subscripted, and if they don't, hide the button.

I made the code of subscription, but it work after the first view did appear. So if try to hide the button when subscription is valid, it will be hidden after the button already appeared.

Now it works like the below:
1. Launch the app
2. Execute the function "checkReceipt()" that checks whether   subscription is valid or not in AppDelegate  (but now always return "false" even it should be valid)
3. the first view appeared
4. Finished checkReceipt() and return true (is valid)

I want to check whether subscription is valid correctly before the first view appeared. How can I solve this problem?

(I use the code for subscription from [here](https://qiita.com/hayashier/items/f05bd4a8bf3b3cefb072))

**AppDelegate**

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, SKPaymentManagerDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var isValid: Bool!

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        // check receipt
        SKPaymentManager.shared().delegate = self
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(SKPaymentManager.shared())

        isValid = SKPaymentManager.checkReceipt()

        return true
    }
//...
```

**SKProductManager**

```
import Foundation
import StoreKit

fileprivate var productManagers : Set<SKProductManager> = Set()

class SKProductManager: NSObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate {
    static var subscriptionProduct : SKProduct? = nil

    fileprivate var completion : (([SKProduct]?,NSError?) -> Void)?

    static func getProducts(withProductIdentifiers productIdentifiers : [String],completion:(([SKProduct]?,NSError?) -> Void)?){
        let productManager = SKProductManager()
        productManager.completion = completion
        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set(productIdentifiers))
        request.delegate = productManager
        request.start()

        productManagers.insert(productManager)
    }

    static func getSubscriptionProduct(completion:(() -> Void)? = nil) {

        guard SKProductManager.subscriptionProduct == nil else {
            if let completion = completion {
                completion()
            }
            return
        }

        let productIdentifier = "secret" 

        SKProductManager.getProducts(withProductIdentifiers: [productIdentifier], completion: { (_products, error) -> Void in
            if let product = _products?.first {
                SKProductManager.subscriptionProduct = product
            }
            if let completion = completion {
                completion()
            }
        })

    }

    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        var error : NSError? = nil
        if response.products.count == 0 {
            error = NSError(domain: "ProductsRequestErrorDomain", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:"couldn't get product"])
        }
        completion?(response.products, error)
    }

    func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        let error = NSError(domain: "ProductsRequestErrorDomain", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:"couldn't get product "])
        completion?(nil,error)
        productManagers.remove(self)
    }
    func requestDidFinish(_ request: SKRequest) {
        productManagers.remove(self)
    }
}
```

**SKPaymentManager**

```
///...
public static func checkReceipt() -> Bool {

var date = NSDate()
var check = false

do {
    let reqeust = try getReceiptRequest()
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: reqeust, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        guard let jsonData = data else { return }

        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .init(rawValue: 0)) as AnyObject
            receiptStatus = ReceiptStatusError.statusForErrorCode(json.object(forKey: "status"))
            guard let latest_receipt_info = (json as AnyObject).object(forKey: "latest_receipt_info") else { return }
            guard let receipts = latest_receipt_info as? [[String: AnyObject]] else { return }
            updateStatus(receipts: receipts)
            var latest = receipts.last

            date = NSDate()
            if let result = latest!["expires_date"] as? String {
                let expireDate = result
                check = checkDifference(now: date, expireDate: expireDate)
                let appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                appDelegate.isValid = check
            }

        } catch _ {

        }
    })
    task.resume()
} catch let error {
    print("SKPaymentManager : Failure to process payment from Apple store: \(error)")
    checkReceiptInLocal()
}

return check

}

/// check subscription is valid or not
fileprivate static func checkDifference(now: NSDate, expireDate: String) -> Bool{

    // convert string to Date
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV"
    let expire = dateFormatter.date(from: expireDate)

    let dateComponentsFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    dateComponentsFormatter.allowedUnits = [.year,.month,.weekOfMonth,.day,.hour,.minute,.second]
    dateComponentsFormatter.maximumUnitCount = 1
    dateComponentsFormatter.unitsStyle = .full

    dateComponentsFormatter.string(from: now as Date, to: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 4000000))  // "1 month"
    dateComponentsFormatter.string(from: expire!, to: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 4000000))  // "1 month"

    let seconds = expire?.seconds(from: now as Date)  

    if seconds! > 0 {
        return true
    }else{
        return false
    }

}
///...
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that checkReceipt() is not an asynchronous call, so nothing is happening when isValid is set. You can accomplish what you want by programmatically setting the initial view for the app in AppDelegate and modifying the checkReceipt() function to accept a closure of type (Bool)->(). If you are using storyboard, you will need to remove the initial view controller first by unchecking "is Initial View Controller" under the View Controller heading in the Attributes inspector.

In SKPaymentManager, change `checkReceipt() -> Bool {` to `checkReceipt(handler:(Bool)->()) {` and then:

```
check = checkDifference(now: date, expireDate: expireDate)
//delete the two lines that follow and replace them with the asynchronous call:
handler(check)
```

IMPORTANT: also remember to add `handler(false)` inside each of the `catch` blocks and the `guard` statement's `else {` block so that the app loads even if there is an error.

Next, in application(:,didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:):

```
//step 1: make variables for window and storyboard. Storyboard name parameter is the storyboard's filename.
var window = UIWindow()
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) 
//step 2: instantiate your initial view controller. 
let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"identifier") as InitialViewController()!
//step 3: make the asynchronous call
checkReceipts(handler: { valid in
    self.isValid = valid
    initialViewController.subscribeButton.isHidden = valid == false //hide if valid
    //step 4: set the window's root view controller 
    window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
})
```

Enjoy :]

Comment: Thank you! But when I tried your code, the error "must be used from main thread only" at AppDelegate and the function in checkReceipts(handler: {}) appeared...

Comment: and  "[Unknown process name] CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable." will appear after a few seconds after the first view did appear.